# Bootstrap button text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 3 custom buttons but can't for some reason change the brand text color nor the dropdown triangles. I've tried a couple of things, but still no luck...

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -30px;">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

  <li class="dropdown" style="margin-right: 70px; margin-left: 60px;" >
    <a class="btn btn-inverse :active" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Wristbands <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown" style="margin-right: 70px;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
      Hawaii <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: are you editing the "bootstrap.css" ? What selectors are you currently using?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/ on that site there is a section captioned "using dropdowns" , "tabs with dropdowns". I am not sure what i should change on my bootstrap.css though.

Comment: Can you please post a link to an example?

Comment: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: whats the error with your website? i saw the dropdown triangles

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I don't see any text in the navbar-brand div.  Is that what you're talking about?

Anyhow, to answer your question, if you have text in navbar-brand, you'd use something like:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

And for the dropdown arrows, something like:

```
span.caret {
  color: red;
}
```